# Load Ruby on Rails partial into jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Does anyone know how I can load a Ruby on Rails partial into a jquery dialog?  I want to do something like this

```
$('#advancedExerciseSearchLink').click(function() {
  $('#advancedSearch').load('/path/to/advancedsearchform_partial').dialog('show');
}
```

I could pre-load the partial on the parent page and just show it when the advanced search button is clicked, but I'd rather dynamically load it because it keeps the initial page load lighter.  I saw some suggestions for using a custom controller action, but I'd like to keep my controller RESTful if possible.

Comment: Are you convinced that dynamic loading of dialog content is worth the effort? Look at it like this. If the dialog content is small then the incremental load time for the page should be insignificant. If the content is large then, if the user were to open and close the dialog multiple times, you would end up transferring more data from the server in the long run and incur the interactive delay with the end-user

Comment: Yeah you're probably right.  I was on a previous project that was a big web app on one page with a ton of dialogs and we had to go with dynamic loading because of the performance hit and also because a lot of times the data in the dialog is dynamic and needs server side processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a "partials_controller.rb" with an action "advanced_search_form" with nothing in it. Then set up the appropriate route, file structure and permissions.

There's nothing not RESTful about that approach.

OR

You can place said file somewhere in the public folder. (Not Recommended as you'll have no control over access permissions.)

I don't really know any other way as jQuery won't be able to access the file because the server won't know what to do with the request.